# Efficient way to find the paths with highest average edge value between two points in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, graph, networkx

Pardon the seemingly confusing phrasing of the question. Here is what I'd like to do.

Given a dataframe **df**

```
Fruit1     Fruit2      Weight
orange     apple       0.2
orange     grape       0.4
orange     pineapple   0.6
orange     banana      0.8
apple      grape       0.9
apple      pineapple   0.3
apple      banana      0.2
grape      pineapple   0.1
pineapple  banana      0.8
```

and a constraint to the highest allowed path length, **L**

I wish to return a dataframe that has the highest average path (i.e. summation of all edges between points/path length to be maximum), where an edge is represented by the **weight** column, given that it does not exceed the length L.

To illustrate with an example of what I mean by highest average path:

Let's say we only have 4 points A, B, C & D. We are interested in finding the highest average path between A & D.

The highest average path would be max( (A->D)/1, (A->B + B->D)/2, (A->C + C->D)/2, (A->B + B->C + C-> D)/3, (A->C + C->B + B-> D)/3 ) in the case of L=3

For L=2, it would be max( (A->D)/1, (A->B + B->D)/2, (A->C + C->D)/2 )

In the case of df, for L=2 we would get something like

```
Fruit1     Fruit2      Weight   MaxAvgPath(L=2)
orange     apple       0.2       [orange, grape, apple]  
orange     grape       0.4       [orange, apple, grape]
orange     pineapple   0.6       [orange, banana, pineapple]
orange     banana      0.8       [orange, banana]
apple      grape       0.9       [apple, grape]
apple      pineapple   0.3       [apple, grape, pineapple]
apple      banana      0.2       [apple, pineapple, banana] 
grape      pineapple   0.1       [grape, orange, pineapple]
grape      banana      0.1       [grape, apple, banana]
pineapple  banana      0.8       [pineapple, banana]
```

Note: This edge set contains just enough rows to represent the entire network. For instance, while (orange, apple) exists, (apple, orange) does not because the weight for (apple, orange) would be the same. However, if including those helps in creating the solution, feel free to use them and leave them out in the final output. The returned paths of the mirror pairs should be equal to the returned paths of the original pairs.

Comment: Can't really do this with pandas. Use something else like BFS or Dijkstra's alg...

Comment: Sure, solutions not involving pandas operations would work too,as long as I can get them back to a pandas dataframe easily. Also, wouldn't something like BFS be a naive solution, given that there would be frequent subpatterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, so you are asking for the path with the highest cost/(number of edges) between each pair of nodes in your graph where the paths are restricted to an upper limit of connecting edges. The longest path problem is np-hard so an efficient solution is only possible with restrictions
 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). I think your limit of edge connections artificially enforces a longest path of length L so could bring it down to exponential in L.

The networkx module can take care of finding our simple paths by a depth-first search and we can rank the paths by manually summing the weights and sorting. We can do that for each pair  of nodes and add that as a new series to the dataframe.

```
import pandas
import networkx

# Create a graph from the dataframe
G = networkx.from_pandas_dataframe(path_frame, 'Fruit1', 'Fruit2', 'Weight')

# Find the longest path between source and target up to length L
def maxpath_cond(G, source, target, edge_attr, L=None):
    #Use networkx simple paths function which uses a depth first search
    paths = networkx.simple_paths.all_simple_paths(G,source, target, L)
    # Calculate and sort the costs of the path
    costs = [(pathcost(G, pth, edge_attr), pth) for pth in paths]
    return sorted(costs, key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True)

def pathcost(G,path, edge_attr):
    lp = len(path)-1
    return sum(G[path[n]][path[n+1]][edge_attr] for n in range(lp))/lp
#Iterate through the dataframe and create a new series made up of long paths
mxs = []
for n in range(len(path_frame)):
    src, targ = path_frame.loc[n]['Fruit1'], path_frame.loc[n]['Fruit2']
    mxl = maxpath_cond(G, src, targ, 'Weight', 2)[0]
    mxs.append( mxl[1])

print(path_frame.assign(MaxAvgPath=mxs))
```

Which outputs:

```
      Fruit1     Fruit2  Weight                   MaxAvgPath
0     orange      apple     0.2       [orange, grape, apple]
1     orange      grape     0.4       [orange, apple, grape]
2     orange  pineapple     0.6  [orange, banana, pineapple]
3     orange     banana     0.8             [orange, banana]
4      apple      grape     0.9               [apple, grape]
5      apple  pineapple     0.3    [apple, grape, pineapple]
6      apple     banana     0.2   [apple, pineapple, banana]
7      grape  pineapple     0.1    [grape, apple, pineapple]
8  pineapple     banana     0.8          [pineapple, banana]
```